# Icon Disappears After Drop-down is Selected (and label value loaded dynamically)

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm adding an icon to a text value in HTML. The problem is that it is being applied to a Bootstrap button. When the drop-down is selected, it takes a value from an external source and the button label changes. When it takes this value, the text inside changes and thus the icon is no longer included. I tried adding it to the div via a class, but that permanently changes the text type, which I do not want to do. Any ideas?

```
  <div class="col-2" style="padding: 20px;">
            <div class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" id="acctFilter" data-toggle="dropdown" acctid="placeholder">
                <i class="fa fa-building"></i>&nbsp; SELECT ACCOUNT
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" id="acctList" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
            </div>
        </div>
```

If I add it like this, the whole button text changes...

```
  <div class="col-2" style="padding: 20px;">
            <div class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split fa fa-globe" id="acctFilter" data-toggle="dropdown" acctid="placeholder">
               SELECT ACCOUNT
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" id="acctList" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom css class to solve this problem like shown in the code snippet below.

Technically, you could add that small piece of custom css to one of the existing classes. But it's better to keep things clean.

The `::before` pseudo-class has a `content` property that allows you to specify what icon/content you want. You'll find the code for that piece by searching for the icon name in this file:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

And `padding-right` allows you to specify the spacing you want between the icon and the text.

Click "run code snippet" below for live testing:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<style>
.icon-building::before {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f1ad";
    padding-right: 10px;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2" style="padding: 20px;">
            <div class="btn icon-building btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" id="acctFilter" data-toggle="dropdown" acctid="placeholder">
                SELECT ACCOUNT
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" id="acctList" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I totally understand, but I am assuming that you have code that handles the click of the drop down. In that code your are changing the text. Without seeing the code, the only suggestion I would have is to wrap the text of the button in a span add a class for easy selection from code and just change the text of the span. So, the html would look like:

```html
<div class="col-2" style="padding: 20px;">
  <div class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" id="acctFilter" data-toggle="dropdown" acctid="placeholder">
    <i class="fa fa-building"></i><span class="my-btn-text">SELECT ACCOUNT<span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="acctList" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
  </div>
</div>
```

If this does not help, please also include any code that modifies the values of the elements.